# How to capture key modifier when Chrome Page Action is clicked

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a page action which when clicked takes the user to a different page.

[image]

When the user clicks the pencil icon in the address bar they are taken to a different page in the current tab, however I would like them to be able to hold down <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>alt</kbd> or <kbd>⇧</kbd> to make this page open in a *new* tab or window. That way they have the option.

Looking through the documentation I can't see if this is possible. It looks like it isn't possible to capture keypresses on page actions. Is this the case?

Comment: No, it is not possible to capture key-presses on page actions. (I am only 99% sure there isn't a viable workaround, so I'll leave it as a comment - don't have high expectations though :))

Comment: @ExpertSystem I'm working on a workaround which uses localStorage to set a flag for if the alt key is pressed or not (`onkeydown` and `onkeyup`) using a content script and message passing. I will post the solution if I find it...

Comment: :) Why didn't **I** think of that first ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a workaround. I can inject a contentscript into the page which listens for `onkeydown` and `onkeyup` events. A flag is saved in localStorage that is set to `false` on page load, `true` if the altKey is pressed and `false` when the altKey is no longer pressed. The background page can then request what the value of this flag was when the page action was clicked...

### contentscript.js

```
// When the page action is clicked this flag could be left as true
// so we always set it to false on page load
localStorage["isAltKeyPressed"] = false;

window.addEventListener('keydown', recordAltKeyPress);
window.addEventListener('keyup', recordAltKeyPress);

function recordAltKeyPress(evt) {
    localStorage["isAltKeyPressed"] = evt.altKey;   
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
        if(request === "isAltKeyPressed") {
            sendResponse( localStorage["isAltKeyPressed"] );
        } else {
            sendResponse(undefined);    
        }
});
```

### background.js

```
// Function to perform when pageAction is clicked
chrome.pageAction.onClicked.addListener(myFunction);

function myFunction(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, "isAltKeyPressed", function(response) {
        // The response comes back as a string, we need a boolean...
        var isAltKeyPressed = (response === "true");
        // Do stuff...
    });
}
```

Comment: +1 Nice work-around ! (BTW, you could still drop the ternary operator and just use: `var isAltKeyPressed = (reponse === "true");` ;)

Comment: Thanks for the tip regarding the ternary (why didn't _I_ think of that?). I spent about a week trying to solve this problem and gave up. Came back to it 2 months later and it comes to me within 5 minutes of posting this question!